# Can you explain differene between them: Wore vs wearing vs Was wearing?

Tags: sentence-construction, past-tense, gerunds

I did some research on the internet and this is what I understand about them:

1. *He wore a black shirt yesterday* means he started and finished the action in yesterday and now he is not in the black shirt.
2. *The boy wearing a red shirt enjoyed cricket* means the boy who wore a red shirt enjoyed cricket.
3. *She was wearing a red dress yesterday.* means she wore a red dress the whole day yesterday.

But still, I don't know if I am right here. I am very much confused.
Please explain these in details with differentiating each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the simple past and the progressive is important when there is a relation between the time of wearing and some other event:

Simple past:
She **wore** a red dress to the party yesterday.

Past progressive:
**When** she arrived yesterday, she **was wearing** a coat.
(She may have taken the coat off later.)

It would be wrong to say
***When** she arrived, she **wore** a coat.
It's wrong because the completed action of wearing a coat doesn't fit into the time frame of "when she arrived".

For your examples,

1. means he wore a black shirt at some time yesterday, maybe all day, but it doesn't say anything about what he's wearing today.
2. either simple past or progressive can be used in expanding the clause because there is no connection to the time of another event.
3. This doesn't imply she wore the dress the whole day, just that there was a time yesterday when she was wearing it.